# cross-browser jQuery issue?

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

I have a simple webpage with two divs. if you hover over the first one the second is shown. When you go directly over the second div it shouldn't hide and if you go elsewhere it should. This works perfect in Chrome but IE and Firefox are hiding the second div no matter what. I found out, that the part

```
!$(this).next().is(":hover")
```

returns `true` in IE and Firefox and `false`in Chrome. Why is this happening?

My code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.d1').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).next().hasClass('d2')) {
      if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
      } else {
        $(this).next().fadeOut();
      }
    }
  }, function() {
    if ($(this).next().hasClass('d2')) {
      if (!$(this).next().is(":hover")) {
        $(this).next().fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.d1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.d2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d1"></div>
  <div class="d2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in CSS alone, which will be more faster and more reliable cross browser. Try this:

```css
.d1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.d2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.d1:hover +.d2, 
.d2:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

Comment: I know, but i wanted to know why this is happening

Comment: Most likely to do with the event handler implementation between browsers.